# Webservice testing using SoapUi - Error with Deserialization and XmlNode[]

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, soapui, xml-deserialization

I am trying to perform a quick testing for a webservice created by a third party.
The problem is whenever I use SoapUI, i am running in to the following error:

> Element MyValue from namespace
> http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Services cannot have child
> contents to be deserialized as an object. Please use XmlNode[] to
> deserialize this pattern of XML.

I understood from [here](http://johnliu.net/blog/2012/9/7/xml-deserialization-cannot-have-child-contents-to-be-deseria.html), that
the DataMember is of type `object` rather than `string` so that the deserializer has problems
in turning a string back into an object of the type `Object`.

One solution suggested was to change the type of DataMember back to `String` which obviously
I cannot because it belongs to a third party.

Any other suggestions to make it work with the SoapUI testing ?

Additional Info: Solution suggested at the blog:

```
[DataContract] 
public class MyClass 
{ 
   [DataMember] 
   public string MyName;

   [DataMember] 
   public object MyValue; 
}
```

If you change your DataContract to

```
 [DataContract] 
 public class MyClass 
 { 
    [DataMember] 
    public string MyName;

    [DataMember] 
    public string MyValue; 
 }
```